# Prove that one circle contains the other circle's radius when six circles meet at one point in a plane

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

**The Problem is:**

Prove that one circle contains the other circle's radius when six circles meet at one point in a plane.

**Comment:**

This problem is one of exercises in my textbook on chapter pigeonhole principle.
To get some hint, I tried drawing identical circles one by one and I could get it by picture. But did not reach the key hint for explaining it by pigeonhole principle. I thought the angle approach could work but didn't find the way to go.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Thanks. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the circles are equal. There are six rays $PO_i$, where $P$ is the common points. Two of them will make an angle smaller than $\frac{2\pi}{6}$, so the distance between the centers will be at most the radius.